# How to search for nodes at the uppermost levels only in Ruby-Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, css-selectors, nokogiri

HTML (particularly MathML) can be heavily nested. With Ruby-Nokogiri, I want to search for a node at the uppermost levels, which are arbitrary, within a parent node. Here is an example HTML/MathML.

1. `<math><semantics>`… (arbitrary depth)

   1. `<mrow>` (call it (1))

      1. `<mrow>` (1-1)
   2. `<mrow>` (2)

      1. `<mrow>` (2-1)
      2. `<mrow>` (2-2)

For a `Nokogiri::HTML` object for it, `page`, `page.css("math mrow")` returns an Array of all the nodes of `<mrow>`, having an Array size of 5 in this case, with the last node being "`<mrow>` (2-2)".

My goal is to identify the last `<mrow>` node at the upper-most level, i.e., "`<mrow>` (2)" in the example above (so that I can add another node after it).

In other words, I want to get the "last node of a certain kind at the shallowest depth among all the nodes of the kind". The depth of the uppermost level for the type of node is unknown and so I cannot limit the depth for the search.

Comment: Are you looking for `"math > mrow"`? ([child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator))

Comment: No, it doesn't work, because `mrow` is not a direct child of `math`. And the depth is arbitrary.

Comment: Oh, I see, I was only looking at the indentation and missed that `<secmantics>...` part after `<math>`.

Comment: You could search for the very first `mrow` in the whole document, go up one step to the parent node (programmatically via Nokogiri) and from there search again for the parent's last (immediate) `mrow` child.

Comment: @Stefan I see, thanks! The strategy should work (providing the first `mrow` lives at the uppermost level among other `mrow`-s, but I can accept the condition!). Would you like to compile it as an answer?

Comment: Sounds like a breadth-first search problem at 1st glance: add a node to the queue, if it's not of the desired type remove it and add its children to the queue _in reversed order_, repeat until you find the desired node (it will be the shallowest one because of BFS properties and the last one because we add children reversed)

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov I didn't know the concept breadth-first search, but after a bit of research, I find it is indeed the case – at least in the general term. Thx for the suggestion. I now realise Nokogiri/CSS/XPath doesn't provide a simple solution and with a good reason. Stefan's suggestion should work in my particular case, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the uppermost `mrow` node in terms of *depth*, you could select among all [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) the one with the least number of [`ancestors`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FNode:ancestors):

```
first_mrow = page.css('mrow:first-of-type').min_by.with_index { |node, index| [node.ancestors.size, index] }
```

Adding [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerator.html#with_index-method) ensures that for nodes with identical number of ancestors, the first one will be picked.

To get the first `mrow` node from the start of the document (regardless of depth), you could simply use:

```
first_mrow = page.at_css('mrow')
```

With the first `mrow` node you can then select its [`parent`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FNode:parent) node:

```
parent = first_mrow.parent
```

and finally retrieve the [`last`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FNodeSet:last) element from the parent's (immediate) `mrow` nodes:

```
last_mrow = parent.css('> mrow').last
```

The latter can also be expressed via the [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) CSS pseudo-class:

```
last_mrow = parent.at_css('> mrow:last-of-type')
```

Comment: I just did a quick check - it seems `at_css` traverses the tree using DFS, so the first found element might be not the shallowest one.

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov you're right, I've fixed it. I could't find a CSS selector for the "shallowest" node, so I resorted to the node's ancestors size.

Comment: This answer can even deal with cases where the first element of `css('mrow')` is located deeper than some others!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a breadth-first search problem at 1st glance: add a node to the queue, if it's not of the desired type remove it and add its children to the queue in reversed order, repeat until you find the desired node (it will be the shallowest one because of BFS properties and the last one because we add children reversed).

Quick and dirty example:

```rb
require "nokogiri"

def find_last_shallowest(root)
  queue = [root]

  while queue.any?
    element = queue.shift
    break element if matching?(element)
    queue += element.children.reverse
  end
end

def matching?(element)
  # Put your matching logic here
  element.name == "m"
end

doc = <<~XML
<foo>
  <bar>
    <m>
      <x></x>
    </m>
  </bar>
  <baz>
  </baz>
  <m>
    <y></y>
  </m>
  <m>
    <z></z>
  </m>
</foo>
XML

xml = Nokogiri::XML(doc)

find_last_shallowest(xml.root) # => #(Element:0xf744 { name = "m", children = [ #(Text "\n    "), #(Element:0xf758 { name = "z" }), #(Text "\n  ")] })
```

It finds `m` thing which has `z` as a child - which is the last and shallowest one...

Comment: This is a neat answer! I guess it is very efficient for generalised cases. I understand (after some contemplation…) this handles a tree node as a tree node, as opposed to an Array like ones returned from `css('XX')`. Much appreciated.